# How to avoid render overflow in flutter in column/wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here I want to avoid render overflow ( I don't want to make it scrollable ) whenever I increase the size of green container .
The red container has scrollable list view as child .I have tried wrapping but it doesn't avoid overflow. Also , if I try to wrap the container of listview builder into expanded I get error . Basically the green container will contain movie description and I want the recommendations in the red container to adjust their size accordingly . Can anyone help?
Here is the code of scaffold body :

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onChanged: (str) {
                    s1 = str;
                  },
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    in1 = double.parse(s1);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                      width: 100,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Text('fytfffffffffffffffffffffffffff'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Text('4.0'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 200,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  Text('Reccomendations'),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: recommendations.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              print(i.toString());
                            },
                            child: Container(
                                child: Text(movies[recommendations[i]])),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image: the photo]

Comment: try wrapping container or row with the SingleChildScrollView